# CTRL+C won't stop a sinatra app

Tags: ruby, console, sinatra

Normally when I run a rails app from the console during development I can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and it exits.  Then I can run the app again, thus bouncing it and effecting changes.

I am running a sinatra app.  I just run the ruby file.

```
$: ruby myapp.rb
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, however, it won't stop the app.  I've had to bring up the Ubuntu System Monitor and kill the Ruby process.  Very annoying.

Anyone seen this/dealt with this before?

Comment: "When I press CTRL+C, however, it won't stop the app." And that's how SkyNet was born kids!

Answer (score 2):

I installed the 'thin' gem and it works fine.

Apparently sinatra + Webrick is unstoppable.

(Also, running Ubuntu 11.04.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the `exit` method, which should exit you out of the Sinatra Irb according to the following reference:

http://sinatra.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Sinatra/Irb.html#M000029