# Running a Sinatra app from within Rails breaks CTRL-C behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, sinatra, jruby, kill

As explained [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#rails-server-start), Rails creates a trap for INT signals as soon as it starts.

I have a Rails app that starts up a Sinatra app in a separate thread.

```
Thread.new do
  begin
    SinatraApp.run!
  rescue => e
    puts e.message
  end
end
```

It seems that running the Sinatra app in a separate thread causes my Rails app to no longer respond to INT signals, meaning I can't kill it via CTRL-C. The Sinatra app "steals" all of the INT signals.

How do I fix this? Is it possible to configure my Rails app so that CTRL-C kills both it and the Sinatra app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Sinatra app was booting up via WEBrick. I found that using another JRuby-based server instead, like [Puma](http://puma.io/) or [Trinidad](https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad) (with the `trap` flag set to `false`), solved the problem.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5900724) helped me find the solution.